# "Which complexity represents a majority of algorithms?"

Tags: algorithms

Student asked me this question. During lectures on algorithm complexity I've shown similar picture ([source](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-time-vs-logarithmic-time-big-o-notation-6ef4227051fb)):

[image: image graph]

After I've explained and gave examples for each category, a student asked: "Which of these represent a majority of algorithms?" I guess that the question is not right in a sense that we are creating new algorithms and that it depends on the field - majority of sorting algorithms are more complex than nlogn.

What would be your answer?

This question is only about the Big O as that was the end of the lecture.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "majority of algorithms", do you mean algorithms that are used or all algorithms? It's possible that a random algorithm on a random input will most likely fail to halt (and the question is sensitive to the representation of programs and the computational model). Also there are infinitely many complexity classes - it seems somewhat unlikely that any one class is appreciably more common than any other.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be that there is no running time that represents the majority of algorithms. Some common algorithms (for example, BFS and DFS) run in linear time; some run in loglinear time (for example, sorting); dynamic programming algorithms run in superlinear polynomial time (for example, the standard algorithm for edit distance runs in quadratic time); algorithms involving matrix multiplication run (practically) in cubic time, and theoretically faster; SAT solvers have worst case exponential running time; and some algorithms involved in verification have even faster growing worst case running time, or are not guaranteed to terminate at all.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part of addressing this question, I would imagine, is the problem of counting algorithms.

Nonetheless, here's an informal way to look at it:

If you pick any integer $n$, there are infinitely more integers larger than $n$ than there are integers smaller than $n$. Similarly, the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) states that you can always solve more problems if you have more time.

This says nothing about the *number* of problems problems in each class, but nonetheless, given an infinite hierarchy of complexity classes, I would be very surprised if, given a complexity class, there are "more" problems outside it than inside it for an appropriate definition of "more".

For example, there are probably more (in the sense of cardinality) decidable problems that are [nonelementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_problem) than there are in the complexity class [ELEMENTARY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY).